# Mark and open multiple files with Helm and Projectile

Tags: helm, projectile

Helm seem to support marking files in `helm-find-files`. Is it possible to open the marked files, each one inside of its own buffer from within the find file buffer?

**Update**: I noticed that I was using `helm-projectile-switch-project` rather than the Helm enhanced `find-file` command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, use `C-SPC` to mark each file individually or mark all with `M-a`, then press `RET` to open all those files. I wrote a [Helm guide here](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) that covers Helm basics and most of default commands. Also check my [helm-projectile](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html). It has the multifile opening right at the beginning.

Aside from the answer above, the question was updated with the question to open multiple files using `helm-projectile-switch-project`. To use `helm-projectile-switch-project` to switch to another project and open multiple files, either `helm-projectile` or `helm-projectile-find-file` must be set to `projectile-switch-project-action`:

```
(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm
      projectile-switch-project-action 'helm-projectile)
```

After that, you can open files in any project (including current projejct) without ever leaving your current working project. This is also explained in [Enter project portal: helm-projectile-switch-project, C-c p p](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html#sec-5) in my guide.

Comment: @Andrea It works a long time ago. Probably you didn't notice, or use `find-file` with Helm's `completing-read`, not `helm-find-files`.

Comment: Most probably I was too distracted with the task at hand and never noticed the buffers were actually being opened! Thanks.

Comment: I figured what's the problem: regardless of the marks I set, if I press RET over an unmarked file, then only that file will be opened in a buffer.

Comment: @Andrea No it's not. If you marked files, Helm always opens marked files regardless where the highlighter is.

Comment: Aha, you are right. Although that's not the case inside the *helm completion* buffer opened with Projectile!

Comment: @Andrea It's the same. Did you use `helm-projectile-find-file` command or `projectile-find-file` with Helm's `completing-read`? If not, you should activate `helm-projectile` with `(helm-projectile-on)`. [A demo](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) at the top of my guide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17776/discussion-between-andrea-and-tu-do).

Comment: I think It's worth updating your answer to reflect the fact that setting the `projectile-completion-system` and `projectile-switch-project-action` variables did the trick for me.

Comment: @Andrea updated.

Comment: ```(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)                                                                                    
(setq projectile-switch-project-action 'helm-projectile)                                                                     
(helm-projectile-on) ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
(projectile-mode +1)                                                                                                         
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "s-p") 'projectile-command-map)                                                         
;; projectile with helm                                                                                                      
(projectile-global-mode)                                                                                                     
(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)                                                                                    
(setq projectile-switch-project-action 'helm-projectile)                                                                     
(helm-projectile-on)
```